# How to use Java Methods/ Parameters

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I have coded a program using separate parts to find & display the area and perimeter of a rectangle. I am now supposed to create a void to display the length, width, area and perimeter. However, I can't seem to get it to display when I run the program. I will pop in my code and then the instructions of the task underneath in case I haven't explained it well enough.

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println (area(10,15));
        System.out.println (perimeter(10, 15));
    }
/**
* Returns the area of a rectangle
*/
    public static int area (int length, int width)
    {
        return length * width;
    }
/**
* Returns the perimeter of the rectangle
*/
    public static int perimeter (int length, int width)
    {
        return 2 * (length + width);
    }
    public static void printRectangleDetails(int length, int width, int area, int perimeter)
    {
        System.out.println ("The length of the rectangle is " + length);
        System.out.println ("The width of the rectangle is " + width);
        System.out.println ("The area of the rectangle is " + area);
        System.out.println ("The perimeter of the rectangle is " + perimeter);
    }
}
```

The task information:
"Write a method called printRectangleDetailswhich, when given the height and width of a rectangle, prints four lines of output stating the height, width, area, and perimeter of the rectangle. The output should include suitable text explaining what the numbers area. Add suitable comments to the new method.printRectangleDetails()is a different kind of method fromareaand perimeter. It performs some actions (printing output) but does not return any result when it is called. Its output type must therefore be voidto show that it does not return a value, and it is an example of a void method. A call to a void method can be used as a standalone statement in your program. However, because a void method does not return a value, it cannot be used where an expression with a value is expected. Methods which return a value (non-void methods) can be used as both standalone statements and as expressions."

Edit - I have now seen this on the instructions "Replace the code in the main method with suitable calls of your printRectangleDetails()method." does this mean I should change the void main(String[] args) section to printRectangleDetails() & if so, how would I do this?

Comment: `System.out.println ("The area of the rectangle is " + area(length, width));`, same for the perimeter.

Comment: Hint: consider to have such discussions with your peers or tutors. Stackoverflow is a poor replacement for such learning activities.

Comment: Hi @GhostCat, I only have one other peer and they don't know either. Our tutors are not available until next week so thought I would ask here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other methods can be called inside methods, you are passing an `int area` and an `int perimeter` in your `printRectangleDetails` parentheses however, you do not have to do this. Your `printRectangleDetails` method should only know the width and height, and inside the method functions then it will call the other methods `area(width, height)` and `perimeter(width, height)` and pass the width and height to them.

For the Edit question, you do not have to change the `main(String[] args)`, but since your new method `printRectangleDetails` already prints all the info of the rectangle including area and perimeter, then all you have to do is replace any methods inside `main` with a single call to `printRectangleDetails`.

Comment: Hi! I totally understand this and your answer helped me to get my head around it, just wondering how would you call it?

Comment: perhaps I can't call it due to it also being public static void? I'm a bit confused because I figured out how to call something but it produces an error

Comment: when you needed to print stuff first, you had to use `System.out.println()` then put the method inside it since they return an int to be printed. however with `printRectangleDetails` you don't have to do this its void that returns nothing, and inside of it exists all the `System.out.println` you want, so to call it is just simpley `printRectangleDetails(width, height);` that would be it, all the print functions will be inside this method and it will print by it self.

Comment: Nevermind I just fixed it, you also have to put the numbers inside the brackets when you call something :).

Comment: I've seen you have just told me that too lol, wondering is there a way not to print the area and perimeter on their own before the rest of the details too? When I remove the system.out.println to the area and perimeter it produces errors

Comment: It should be safe for them to be removed from `main` and only `printRectangleDetails()` line will be just fine in `main` by itself, unless the instructor said otherwise.
I'm not sure where the error coming from, if you're still having error post the code after it got modified.

Comment: the error was because I left the brackets before the area and perimeter when they should have been removed lol how silly of me. Thank u so much for the help !!